# Easiest way to make a dynamic, editable list of simple objects in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want a dynamic array of mutable strings to be presented by a mother view with a list of child views, each presenting one of the strings, editable. Also, the mother view will show a concatenation of the strings which will update whenever one of the strings are updated in the child views.

Can't use (1) `ForEach(self.model.strings.indices)` since set of indices may change and can't use (2) `ForEach(self.model.strings) { string in` since the sub views wants to edit the strings but `string` will be immutable.

The only way I have found to make this work is to make use of an `@EnvironmentObject` that is passed around along with the parameter. This is really clunky and borders on offensive.

However, I am new to swiftui and I am sure there a much better way to go about this, please let know!

Here's what I have right now:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SimpleModel : Identifiable { var id = UUID(); var name: String }
let simpleData: [SimpleModel] = [SimpleModel(name: "text0"), SimpleModel(name: "text1")]
final class UserData: ObservableObject { @Published var simple = simpleData }

struct SimpleRowView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
  var simple: SimpleModel
  var simpleIndex: Int { userData.simple.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == simple.id })! }
  var body: some View {
    TextField("title", text: self.$userData.simple[simpleIndex].name)
  }
}

struct SimpleView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
  
  var body: some View {
    let summary_binding = Binding<String>(
      get: {
        var arr: String = ""
        self.userData.simple.forEach { sim in arr += sim.name }
        return arr;
      },
      set: { _ = $0 }
    )
    
    return VStack() {
      TextField("summary", text: summary_binding)
      ForEach(userData.simple) { tmp in
        SimpleRowView(simple: tmp).environmentObject(self.userData)
      }
      Button(action: { self.userData.simple.append(SimpleModel(name: "new text"))}) {
        Text("Add text")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where the `EnironmentObject` is created and passed as `SimpleView().environmentObject(UserData())` from AppDelegate.

**EDIT:**

For reference, should someone find this, below is the full solution as suggested by @pawello2222, using ObservedObject instead of EnvironmentObject:

```
import SwiftUI

class SimpleModel : ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID(); @Published var name: String
  init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

class SimpleArrayModel : ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID(); @Published var simpleArray: [SimpleModel]
  init(simpleArray: [SimpleModel]) { self.simpleArray = simpleArray }
}

let simpleArrayData: SimpleArrayModel = SimpleArrayModel(simpleArray: [SimpleModel(name: "text0"), SimpleModel(name: "text1")])

struct SimpleRowView: View {
  @ObservedObject var simple: SimpleModel
  var body: some View {
      TextField("title", text: $simple.name)
  }
}

struct SimpleView: View {
  @ObservedObject var simpleArrayModel: SimpleArrayModel
  
  var body: some View {
    let summary_binding = Binding<String>(
      get: { return self.simpleArrayModel.simpleArray.reduce("") { $0 + $1.name } },
      set: { _ = $0 }
    )
    
    return VStack() {
      TextField("summary", text: summary_binding)
      ForEach(simpleArrayModel.simpleArray) { simple in
        SimpleRowView(simple: simple).onReceive(simple.objectWillChange) {_ in self.simpleArrayModel.objectWillChange.send()}
      }
      Button(action: { self.simpleArrayModel.simpleArray.append(SimpleModel(name: "new text"))}) {
        Text("Add text")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set of indices may change"?

Comment: @NewDev When adding a new text to the array, the array's index set will change and a ForEach on indices is only allowed if the set of indices is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need an `@EnvironmentObject` (it will be available globally for all views in your environment).

You may want to use `@ObservedObject` instead (or `@StateObject` if using SwiftUI 2.0):

```
...
return VStack {
    TextField("summary", text: summary_binding)
    ForEach(userData.simple, id:\.id) { tmp in
        SimpleRowView(userData: self.userData, simple: tmp) // <- pass userData to child views
    }
    Button(action: { self.userData.simple.append(SimpleModel(name: "new text")) }) {
        Text("Add text")
    }
}
```

```
struct SimpleRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
    var simple: SimpleModel
    ...
}
```

Note that if your data is not constant you should use a dynamic `ForEach` loop (with an explicit `id` parameter):

```
ForEach(userData.simple, id:\.id) { ...
```

However, the best results you can achieve when you make your `SimpleModel` a *class* and `ObservableObject`. Here is a better solution how do do it properly:

[SwiftUI update data for parent NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62612917/8697793)

Also, you can simplify your `summary_binding` using `reduce`:

```
let summary_binding = Binding<String>(
    get: { self.userData.simple.reduce("") { $0 + $1.name } },
    set: { _ = $0 }
)
```